# What Are Global attributes In HTML

Tags: html

what are Global attributes in html? And is there a list of all the Global attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) specification introduced the concept of Global Attributes. These are attributes that may be specified on all HTML elements. The list should be the following:

```
accesskey
class
contenteditable
contextmenu
dir
draggable
hidden
id
lang
spellcheck
style
tabindex
title
```

Source and further reading:

- [W3.ORG: HTML5 - 3.2.3 Global attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#global-attributes)

Comment: Is there a list in w3.org docs or any where if so can you point me to it thanks!

Comment: @snub: Added a reference in my answer :)